# How to merge push and email in a single journey?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions, mobilepush, push

We have a separate journey for wishlist email and another one for push.
We wish to merge these 2 into a single journey.
Say for example the new data extension then has below fields,

```
ContactKey : hashed email
Email : a@gmail.com
Device ID : xyz
```

This data extension has below SUBSCRIBER RELATIONSHIP

```
 ContactKey relates to Subscribers on Subscriber Key
```

If I use this DE as an entry source will I be able to merge push + email in a single journey? And I am not pretty clear about how to set this up? Can anyone guide me what is the ideal setup for merging push and email?

Comment: What's the rationale for merging them?  It's not a bad approach to build more, smaller journeys than fewer, more complex ones.

Comment: The reason is we want to have everything in a single journey and want to check if contact has a push then send a push instead of email when they enter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should not be a problem of using two communication channels within one journey. However, you do have to meet some conditions to correctly perform send-outs.

- Your Data Extension's fields and subscriber relationship are already in place which is good, however, you also need to make sure that values within the "ContactKey" field will be the same for both channels for one contact.
- Before adding push notifications into journeys, be sure to review your entry source data extensions. To successfully send a push notification using Journey Builder, ensure there is a contact key in the data extension and that the contact has an associated device ID, device token, and platform type registered within Marketing Cloud ([source](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/app-messaging-with-mobilepush/create-push-messages-in-journey-builder))

Other than that, there should not be any problems with doing that.